# Requests 1.0.4 asynchronous requests

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, python-requests

I use the Python Requests library. Today I upgraded from Requests 0.12.1 to 1.0.4.

After upgrading the *async* module doesn't work anymore, and you are advised to use *grequests*. However, *grequests* doesn't work with Requests 1.0.4.

I already filed an issue in the lib's GitHub: https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests/issues/29

Does somebody have a workaround or patch for this issue?

Comment: I remember it did, it's a while ago ;) But, I guess they fixed this by now, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/sigmavirus24/grequests

I'm working on updating grequests to 1.0.4 but haven't gotten around to properly testing it to make sure it works perfectly. If you would like, please post issues on my project so the pull request I've set up at https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests will be perfect.

Comment: Good job, I will keep you posted on issues!

Comment: @TTT let me just make sure I have issues tracking turned on for the fork ;)

Comment: Yeah, just turned it on. Feel free to accept this if the answer suits your needs ;)